# What is the maximum limit for a dropdown box values in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

In my application I am pupulating the dropdown box fatching data from database.

Problem:

The page response time is very high if the dropdown value is increased. Is there any Maximum limit for dropdown box in ASP? or do we need to populate it some other way?

Please advice.

Thanks
Suman

Answer (score 1):

There's no imposed limit, but you have to consider how much data the user should be required to download on each page view. If the page is taking an undesirably long time to load than you ought to think about fetching only a subset of the data initially and then either loading the rest incrementally using AJAX or providing some kind of wizard to get to the next subset.

As an alternative, it might make more sense to use a textbox and implement the [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin in order to return data as the user types in the field, rather than populating a drop down.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question, but I was thinking about how big commercial sites like Dell or NVidia handle things like this.  Normally they would never present the user with a drop down that had more than like 10 choices.  A lot of times they present a series of screens and ask you more and more granular questions, to narrow down the choice.  This could be implemented with a series of drop downs that are dynamically populated by the previous choice, list boxes, or just a series of pages.

Anyway, I'd try to stay away from pushing the limits of ASP for a drop down, there might be a more elegant solution, if there's any way for you to successively filter down the choices.